# How to play upper voices of this piano arrangement part of Pachelbel's Canon

Tags: piano, fingering

I am not quite sure how to play best the upper two voices of measures 2 and 3 in the picture below in a piano arrangement of Pachelbel's Canon in D. My first idea was to use the left hand and play the meldoy with my right hand, but it says "m.d." which I assume means "right hand". Any suggestions?
[image]

Comment: Note that the left hand is filled with 10ths. If you can't play those with one hand alone because your hands are too small (I know mine are), you have a lot of rearranging to do.

Answer (score 1):

"M.d." would mean "main droit" or "mano destra" (right hand). Either the arranger has intended those notes to be played with the right hand, or they have made a mistake and what they really meant was the left hand.

If you play those notes with the right hand you could play the lower part on the upper stave with your left hand. Or you could ignore the marking and play those notes with the left hand. Since this is an arrangement I suggest you do whatever works best for you

Comment: "m.d." is typically paired with the Italian "m.s." ("mano sinistra") in sheet music.

Comment: @Dekkadeci In French piano music "m.d" is paired with "m.g.". But the question was about "m.d.", and that means the same in either Italian or French: "main droit" vs. "mano destra".

Answer (score 1):

As this is an arrangement I would arrange it in a way I can play it. (I really doubt that this is a good transcription).

I‘d play the notes marked  m.d. with the left hand and the chord on the 1st beat with the right hand  (3th 8va).